# Why can I access a private struct member outside the class

Tags: c++, class, unions, private-members, anonymous-struct

When I access this private struct member, the msvc compiler told me that I can't access the member, but I can run the code successfully.

but if I left the struct member out, the code can't run

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    union{
         struct{
            char* c;
         };
    };
};

void fun(A* tmp) {
    //like this,note me can't access,but have no error
    tmp->c = new char('a');
}

int main(void) {

    A t;
    fun(&t);
    std::cout << t.c;
    return 0;
}

//can't run,me can't access and have a "can't access" error
class A{
....
private:
    union{

    };
    struct{
        char* c; 
    };
....
};
```

txt output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: c++11test, Configuration: Debug x64 ----- 
-
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\wirbelwind\documents\visual studio 
2015\projects\json\c++11test\main.cpp(52): warning C4091: 'static ': ignored 
on left of 'a' when no variable is declared
1>  c++11test.vcxproj -> D:\Wirbelwind\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\json\x64\Debug\c++11test.exe
1>  c++11test.vcxproj -> D:\Wirbelwind\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\json\x64\Debug\c++11test.pdb (Full PDB)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I edited the code,this code can do test.
i use vs2015(tool v140)

Comment: Anonymous struct is nonstandard.

Comment: MSVC's bug? https://wandbox.org/permlink/sXckuqGyLkLCEXzb

Comment: Cannot reproduce. g++ rightfully complains with "‘char* A::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::c’ is private within this context". Looks like you found a bug in your compiler.

Comment: This is not valid C++ code. Possibly a non-standard extension at work. If you are getring any compiler messages, post them verbatim.

Comment: Your screenshots look as if Visual Studio recognizes the errors in your code. However, if you have build errors and try to run your code, Visual Studio shows a dialog _There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?_ Maybe you clicked _Yes_ together with _Do not show this dialog again_ before. There also is a project setting _On Run, when build or deployment errors occur_, which can be set to _Launch old version_.

Comment: @pschill I did not clicked the dialog,and ran the code sucessfully on another computer with the same msvc version(tool v140).I set Launch old version to Do not launch,it also ran successfully.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Programs and error messages are text. Thanks. Your compiler is telling you your program contains errors. Whatever you are running is not your program.

Comment: @n.m.Sorry,i deleted screenshots and add a new screenshot,you can see some details.

Comment: @NanaNoe We are asking you to post *text*, not (another) screenshot.

Comment: @L.F. I think screenshot is more clear....